# Does fail2ban start automatically each time system starts?

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, fail2ban

I've just installed Fail2ban on Ubuntu 14.04 and there's something I want to ask:
Does fail2ban start automatically each time system starts? I think so, but just want to make sure, since I've read somewhere online that one should use chkconfig command to autostart fail2ban (not like Ubuntu has this command anyhow)...

Answer (score 7):

Normally it should. 
To be sure you can check with:

```
ls -al /etc/init.d/fail2ban
```

and

```
ls -al /etc/rc*.d/ | grep fail2ban
```

If you don't see fail2ban listed, you can use the following command to enable it:

```
update-rc.d fail2ban enable
```